# how can make runtime ListView with binding? wpf

Tags: listview, binding, datatemplate, gridviewcolumn, frameworkelementfactory

for example I can't get result from this code! please help me, tnx. :)

```
        GridViewColumn gvc6 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc6.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("sum");

        FrameworkElementFactory txt = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        txt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding()); // sets binding


        gvc6.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(string));
        gvc6.CellTemplate.VisualTree = txt;
```